# Play random video on page with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, video, random, append

I have three videos that I'd like to show randomly on each page load. I have the basic code which produces the correct URL, and it shows correctly in the page source with Google dev tools. However, the video won't play.
If I hard code the URL the video plays fine, so it's almost as if the code needs to append the url before it executes the video?

Here's what I have so far:

```
var poster = document.querySelector('#videoposter');
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
source.src += number +'.mp4';
poster.poster += number +'.jpg';
```

```
<video preload="none" playsinline="" loop="" muted="" autoplay="" onplaying="this.controls=false;document.getElementById('vidOverlay').style.display = 'none';" poster="/images/media/Poster-" id="videoposter">
<source id="homevideo" src="/images/media/Video-" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, for the scenario you describe:

```
<video preload="none" controls playsinline loop muted poster="/images/media/Poster-" id="videoposter">
<source id="homevideo" src="/images/media/Video-" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
var poster = document.getElementById('videoposter');
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
poster.src += number +'.mp4';
poster.poster += number +'.jpg';
</script>
```

The changes I made:

- the script needs to run after the element is present in the DOM (so if can access the properties of the element), so either in-line after the element on the page, or in a function that's triggered on a page loaded event
- you're referencing the element with the `videoposter` ID, so I accessed it directly and specifically
- in your script you were updating `source.src` rather than `poster.src`
- `controls`, `playslinline`, `loop`, `muted` etc are binary properties so if present they are true, if absent they are false.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to just create a `<video>` tag dynamicaly on page load:

Try this code in a blank document and see if it, does what you want? 
(Apply same code logic into your own)...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div> <a id="myVideoTag"> </a> </div>

<script>

//# generate random number
var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
var mySrc = "/images/media/Video-" + number + ".mp4";

//# create video element to append into above <a> tag           
tmpElement = document.createElement( "video");
tmpElement.setAttribute("controls", "true" );
tmpElement.setAttribute("width", "800");
tmpElement.setAttribute("src", mySrc);

//# append the dynamically created element...
var container = document.getElementById("myVideoTag");
container.appendChild(tmpElement);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```